# Javascript: how to extract string from attribute via Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I extract the string from a certain `data` attribute via regexp.

```
<button data-loading-text="Some text on loading" data-toggle="button">Button</button>
<button data-finished-text="Some text on finished" data-toggle="button">Button</button>
```

And my javascript is

```
var Buttons = document.querySelectorAll([data-toggle="button"]);
[].forEach.call(Buttons, function (item) {
    var data = item.getAttribute('data-'+INEEDTHIS+'-text')
    var option = INEEDTHIS
    return new Button(item,option);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) property:

```
var attrs = item.attributes;
for(var i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var m = attrs[i].name.match(/^data-(.*)-text$/);
    if (m) {
        var option = m[1];
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) method of jQuery

Comment: I know jQuery cand do attr(), I need native Javascript.